# Switch console in companion app for Call of Duty: Advanced Warfare

Tags: call-of-duty-advanced-warfare

I have purchased Call of Duty: Advanced Warfare on both Xbox One and PS4 to be able to play with all my friends.

I also logged onto [callofduty.com](http://callofduty.com) and verified that both my Xbox account and my PSN account has been linked to my profile.

I then installed the companion app on my iPad and logged onto my Call of Duty profile.

In the app, I can only see my Xbox One soldier and information. There's no information indicating that I even have a PSN account or a soldier.

Can I switch to my PSN account and view that soldier, or is the app limited to just one console?

Answer (score 1):

A bit cumbersome but to switch, do the following in the companion app.

1. Bring up the menu (menu button lower right, looks like 3 horizontal stripes)
2. Select "Account Settings", the next-to-last item on the menu
3. Choose between:

   - USE XBOX LIVE ACCOUNT
   - USE PSN ACCOUNT
   - USE STEAM ACCOUNT
4. Exit back out of the menu

The soldier on the newly selected platform will now load.